# saving and loading custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Iphone development. My problem is I have an `NSMutableArray` of some custom object. Each object has 4 properties i.e a name(`NSString`),an Image(`UIImage`), a button(`UIButton`) and a boolean value  associated with it. Buttons are randomly generated programatically and placed on a view when the view loads(inside `viewDidLoad`). How do I save this array of objects and regenerate it whenever the user exits and then reenters the application.The buttons must also retain their position on the view.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use ARC, a kind of GC.
All objects are released when they go out of reference.
I can show you 2 idea to retain those objects.

1: Retain those objects on a parent ViewController or Delegate class.

You can declare all objects in advance on parent ViewControler or Delegate class.

```
NSMutableCustomArray *customArray = [NSMutableCustomArray array];
[customArray setParameters];
ChildView *childView = [[ChildView alloc] init];
[customArray setCustomArray:customArray];
[self.view addSubview:ChildView];
```

All objects in a customArray does not go out reference unless parent exists.

2: Use CoreData or NSUserDefaults.

NSUserDefaults is so useful if you want to simple data, string, bool and so on.
As for UIButton, it's tiring that you have to restore position.

```
[defaults setObject:string forKey:@"customString"];
[defaults setFloat:10.0 forKey:@"button_x"];
[defaults setFloat:10.0 forKey:@"button_y"];
[defaults setFloat:10.0 forKey:@"button_width"];
[defaults setFloat:10.0 forKey:@"button_height"];
```

Comment: Instead of manually handling the x/y/width/height individually, you could use `NSStringFromCGRect()` encode the `frame` as string, and store that string in `NSUserDefaults`. When loading, you'd use `CGRectFromString()` to create a CGRect from the string.

Comment: @Kitsune That was so helpful..! :)..Thank You so much!..Its lot less tiring to use `NSStringFromCGRect()` to save the button frames.